Company threatening me after I changed my mind on joining them after observing their work style
Company A, which I was about to join, had some issues with my notice period for the current employer. They were ready to give me a fake work experience letter stating that I worked for them for the time I had been with my current employer. I was quite reluctant and spoke multiple times against this, but I was constantly pressured by them.
It came to a point where A was forcing me to work for them even before I joined them. I reluctantly agreed as it was a new domain entirely for which I had little to no experience. I thought it was okay to attend few meetings to get a hang of things and see for myself the team I'd be working with. However, during that knowledge gaining period, I realized there were a lot of inconsistencies between what was communicated to me before vs what I observed. I would have to work on weekends due to inefficiencies from the top. The delivery model too was quite weird, so weird, that they were ready to deploy a feature in a day when QA had not analyzed on it completely yet.
Looking at all this, I felt that it was best for me to say I was not going to join them as I prefer to spend my weekend time with my family and not cry about work then, something which they didn't tell at all.
I sent an email mentioning this. In return, I got a call, more of a personal attack than professional. They started threatening me by calling HR from my current employer.
I didn't sign any joining letter apart from the offer letter nor have I taken any salary. Do these threats make sense?

Did you already hand in your notice at your previous employer ? What did they need the "fake" letter for? Anything illegal or for fraud?

I did put in my papers, but couldn't negotiate notice. So without completing notice, I won't be getting any experience or relieving certificates needed in the future. So they ended up faking one.

@NoMansLand - It's my understanding you didn't leave your current employment nor did you actually stay on as an employee to this new company, so what exactly is the problem?

"relieving certificates" -- So is this in India? Adding that tag is very helpful, as labor practices and document requirements are so unique/unusual there.

Since you already attempted to put in your papers, your employer is already aware that you were planning on leaving. Since your papers were not accepted, you haven't officially left your old employer. Unless I am missing something, the rejected new employer doesn't seem to have much to hold over your head.

I wouldn't be too concerned about the threats. I am not sure if you intended or now intend to keep your current job. Hope that's not a headache. I also hope you and your now rejected would-be employer were careful in formulating your current "trial" period -- how the compensation works and in what capacity you joined. If you join on an ad hoc basis, they should not expect otherwise. And if it's more than just a few meetings, like more than a few hours, I'd be concerned about an employer willingly use your hours without compensating you even before these red flags.

Even if you signed a contract, resigning it is usually a no issue pending on your locale

In the original title, it seems you told company A you were not going to join them a day before your working contract was due to begin. (I was about to join a company, but rejected a day before cause of their observed work ethics.) Is this true? That was my only reservation before approving the edit. If true, this relevant detail should be edited in.

I believe your question is the closest you can get from an answers. When dealing with a problematic employer, it's crucial to maintain clarity and transparency in communication, especially in case of potential retaliation. Based on your points: 1. The initial offer from the company did not match what was presented.
2. The company attempted to create fraudulent documents, which should have raised significant concerns.
3. You were coerced into working unpaid hours, which, although you acknowledge some responsibility, should have been a warning sign.
4. During this time, the company's true colors

The whole relieving-letter system -- part of India's attempt to make sure nobody is working two jobs, apparently -- seems from my non-Indian point of view to be institutionalized blackmail. I have stopped even trying to answer questions tagged "India" because I don't understand it and, I suspect, never will. Others may want to read up on this mess before attempting to give answers; what works elsewhere may not work here.

I would consider yourself lucky.  It was great to learn about what a horrible work environment company A had prior to joining.  Just don't speak with them again.  Do not take their phone calls or answer their emails.
As far as the threats, there is really nothing that they can do.  It is okay to consider other job opportunities and I am sure your current employer will not fault you for doing so.  Company A wanted you to lie about work experience and you said "No".  Good job for remaining honest.
Even though they are threatening you, there is really nothing that they can do to hurt you.  Just ignore them and count yourself lucky.

I do agree with the advise, but still, it's probably based on a wrong premise. It sounds like op has a contract ("signed the offer letter") and a contract is enforceable via a court. So either you know something I don't which is missing here or your answer is reasoned with something that's simply false.

@DonQuiKong The OP's English makes it hard to be sure, but it sounds like the representations in the offer letter weren't accurate.

@DonQuiKong "a contract is enforceable via a court"  I would be very surprised to see a court forcing someone to work for a company.  The contract enforces the obligation to work if you accept payment (and that they have to pay you if you work, even badly), and the only punishment would normally be a court telling to to return the money you took but did not work for.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine: That may or may not be true for India, but in other countries (definitely in Germany, and I would guess many other European countries), work contracts do specify notice periods. Obviously, nobody can physically force you to work, but you are liable for the damages arising from your breach of contract. That most companies won't bother because these damages are hard to quantify and prove is another matter.

@StephenG-HelpUkraine as Stefan says, that's wrong in at least some parts of the world, probably most. @ Accumulation thank you.

@Stefan I'm not disagreeing with you, however most European contracts will also include some kind of probationary period at the start where the notice period is particularly short for exactly this kind of "this isn't the job / company / culture fit I hoped it would be" situation, meaning under such a contract OP could pretty much do exactly as they have described.

I also wonder if bringing up "they tried to get me to give a fake work experience letter" in such a court case would be an argument towards invalidating the contract on some grounds — or if even the prospect of entering that into evidence would be enough to get the company to drop it silently.

If Company A is calling your current Companies HR department and saying things that may or may not be true - I would be rather happy...
1: Tortious interference
2: Defamation and Slander
3: Probably some other workers rights
Those first two I am rather certain about - and it would give good grounds to threaten to sue and get a settlement.

Be careful with the second, unless you know what has been said; they might just tell them "xyz was supposed to start working for us, I hope shkle can do a nice job now that shkle remains with you".

Are you sure those options are available to someone in India?

@Pyrotechnical That will most likely depend on how willing they are to bribe court officials - something the question asker here has not indicated one way or another.

@Pyrotechnical - So the first two are based in English Common Law - which I believe is the basis for the Indian legal system - I would be well surprised if there was neither a Defamation law or Tort law in India.

@TheDemonLord You are missing the point. It doesn't matter what the law says on paper without a properly functioning court system to enforce it; India lacks one. Just google and read Indians' experiences with their legal system. India is a deeply corrupt society; you may never even get a case heard unless you are willing to grease the palms of court bureaucrats, judges, or both. In such a society, suing - and thus also, credibly threatening to sue - is a course of action only available to those willing to indulge in corruption. An honest person threatening it is liable to just be laughed at.

@MarkAmery - I cant speak to the level of corruption in India - but if it is as you say - then a bribe and a threat would seem to be a good start.

This answer doesn't seem to address the specifics of the Indian workplace

@mattfreake The India tag was added to the question after this answer was written - and not by the OP. I don't see if the OP has confirmed that it is, in fact, India, though commenters (perhaps correctly) guessed they were were in India from some things the OP said.

Regarding the 2nd point, I'm not sure about in OP's country, but here in the U.S., defamation/slander could only apply if the things stated were untrue - and known by the person who said them to be untrue. Company A calling company B and telling them "Employee C had accepted an offer with us, but backed out" would be true and, thus, not defamation. Granted, I doubt company B would care, so it would be a pretty poor threat here. As far as signing an offer letter, whether any breach of contract occurred would depend on the offer. That would normally not be a breach here, for example.
